# how to convert a cell to string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

Suppose I have a cell

```
v =    'v'    [576.5818]    [3.0286]    [576.9270]

       'v'    [576.5953]    [3.1180]    [576.8716]

       'f'    [      56]    [    58]    [      52]

       'f'    [      56]    [    58]    [      52]
```

and I want to convert this to a cell array using a format string for each element:`'   %.5f'`

How can I do this? I tried the following approach, but I get an error:

```
f1 = @(x) sprintf('   %.5f',x);
cellfun(f1, num2cell(v),'UniformOutput', false)
```

I am getting an error as ???

> `Error using ==> sprintf`
>
> `Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.`
>
> `Error in ==> @(x)sprintf('   %.5f',x)`

Can any one help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 21):

## String is a cell array

Well, not really.. It is a matrix, but continue reading.

I guess cell array is the most mystic data type in MATLAB. So let's **demystify** it a bit ;-)

Assume

```
fruits = {...
    'banana',...
    'apple',...
    'orange'...
}
```

First of all integer indexing is not needed for small arrays. It is much better to use **foreach**-like constructions. Indeed,

```
for index = 1:numel(fruits)
    fruits{index}
end
```

is equivalent to

```
for fruit = fruits
    fruit
end
```

right?

Well, not quite. First loop produces strings, while the second one gives cells. You can check it with

```
for index = 1:numel(fruits)
    [isstr(fruits{index}) iscell(fruits{index})]
end

for fruit = fruits
    [isstr(fruit) iscell(fruit)]
end
```

, i.e. **[1 0]** and **[0 1]**.

If you have spot the difference, then you must know what to do with the next example (in this one is really relate to your question **(!)** I promise!).  Say you try to do horizontal concatenation in a loop:

```
for fruit = fruits
    [fruit 'is a fruit']
end
```

You will get

```
ans = 

    'banana'    'is a fruit'
```

and so on. Why? Apparently this code tries to concatenate a nested cell array to a string (a cell array containing a matrix of chars which constitute the string like 'banana'). So, correct answer is

## Use {:}

```
for fruit = fruits
    [fruit{:} 'is a fruit']
end
```

Magically this already produces the expected *'banana is a fruit'*, *'apple is a fruit'*, etc.

## Hints

A few hints:

- Index-free looping works nicely with structs as in `for fruit = [fieldnames][1](fruits)'`
- The above is *true* for open source **octave**
- banana is not just fruit, taxonomically it is also a herb ;-) just like 'banana' in MATLAB is both a string and a matrix, i.e. assert(isstr('banana') && ismat('banana')) passes, but assert(iscell('banana')) fails.
- `{:}` is equivalent to `cell2mat`

## PS

a solution to your question may look like this:

Given

```
vcell = {...
    'v'    576.5818    3.0286  576.9270;
    'v'    576.5818    3.0286  576.9270    
}
```

covert index-wise only numeric types to strings

```
 vcell(cellfun(@isnumeric, vcell)) =  cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%.5f', x), vcell(cellfun(@isnumeric, vcell)), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Above code outputs

vcell =

```
'v'    '576.58180'    '3.02860'    '576.92700'
'v'    '576.58180'    '3.02860'    '576.92700'
```

which can be concatenated.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we have a cell as follows:

```
my_cell = {'Hello World'}  
class(my_cell)
ans = 
cell
```

We can get the string out of it simply by using the `{:}` operator on it directly.

```
   class(my_cell{:})
    ans =
    char
```

Note that we can use the expression `mycell{:}` anywhere we would use a normal string.

Comment: Way to go! Never say gravedigging never helped anybody.

Comment: calling superfluous function call `sprintf` a hack - is a lol

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sprintf('   %.5f',x{:})
```

(Works according to some [Google results](https://www.google.be/search?q=matlab%20sprintf%20cell).)

Answer (score 2):

By looking in the strjoin.m file i found this:

```
string = [x{:}];
```