# How to extract a string from a table cell in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, csv, cell

I imported a csv file `data_tr` in Matlab,

```
1, abc
2, def
...
```

Now intended to use the strings in my code like

```
save_location = strcat('trial\tr_',data_tr(i,2),'.png');
```

This resulted in the following error:

> Inputs must be character vectors, cell arrays of character vectors, or string arrays.

The variable `data_tr(i,2)` was considered a 1x1 table and not a string.

After seeing some answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258508/how-to-convert-a-cell-to-string-in-matlab) one), I also tried this:

```
da = data_tr(i,2);
h = [da{:}];
save_location = strcat('trial\tr_',h,'.png');
```

But this showed a subscripting error:

> Error using main (line 14 (ie line h=[da{:}];) )
>
> You cannot subscript a table using linear indexing (one subscript) or multidimensional indexing (three or more
> subscripts). Use a row subscript and a variable subscript.

Can anyone help me to extract the string from the csv file.

Comment: Did you try what the [documentation tells you](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) and use `save_location=strcat('trial\tr_',data_tr{i,2},'.png');`?

Comment: Yes, i used the **help strcat**. It takes strings as input. moreover `strcat(int2str(28),'trial.png')` works fine. The problem is that `da=data_tr(i,2);` is considered as a 1x1 table by matlab (shown in the var section) and i dont know how to extract the string from it.

Comment: You can try using  `data_tr.Var2{i,1}`. The table will automatically assign `Var1`, `Var2`, etc as variable names in a table, so your second column should be `Var2`.

Comment: That worked. I went to the import data section and while importing, renamed the columns as col_1 and col_2.
 `data_tr.col_1(i)` was the correct syntax though.
Thanks a lot! **Resolved**

Comment: Please actually read the documentation I linked. There is a difference between `()` and `{}`.

Comment: @excaza thanks. i couldn't understand that before. 
`data_tr{i,2}` for the element and 
`data_tr(i,2)` for the sub-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either access the table element using curly braces

```
data_tr{i,2} % Get the element of a table rather than data_tr(I,2)
```

Or convert it to a cell, since `strcat` can take cell inputs

```
data_tr_cell = table2cell(data_tr);
data_tr_cell(i, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks! i didn't know either. The later method is more useful as the output of the **strcat ** is also cells.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're loading the data by hand using some import tool (such as [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool-app.html)). You could likely make things easier for yourself by instead [loading the data programmatically](https://www.mathworks.com/videos/importing-data-from-files-programmatically-71077.html). This would let you tailor the loading of your data to the specific file format you're using and have more control over the data formatting.

For example, for your given sample file you could use [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html):

```
[~, strData] = xlsread('data_tr.csv');  % Load string data into a cell array
strData = strtrim(strData);             % Remove leading or trailing blanks
...
save_location = strcat('trial\tr_', strData{i}, '.png');  % Access a string
```

Or you could use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html):

```
fid = fopen('data_tr.csv', 'r');               % Open file for reading
C = textscan(fid, '%*d%s', 'Delimiter', ',');  % Read just the strings
fclose(fid);                                   % Close file
strData = C{1};                                % Remove cell encapsulation
...
% Use the same way as above
```

Comment: I was using csvread for the data, but to rename the columns i manually imported the table. Anyway it would have created the same 300x2 table and i didnt knew the use of **curly braces** to access the string. Though thanks for the advice!